# How to make acmart stop complaining about \baselinestretch?

Tags: baseline, acmart

I have a document in `acmart` style, which uses some old package. This package modifies `baselinestretch` somehow. In the end, I see this in the log:

```
Class acmart Error: An attempt to redefine \baselinestretch detected. 
Please do not do this for ACM submissions!.
```

What would be a reasonable workaround? I can't change the package. I just want `acmart` to stop printing this error message. I also don't want to modify `acmart.cls`. It seems that that I should add something right before `\end{document}` to reset this length back to what `acmart` expects...

The code I have is this:

```
\documentclass[sigplan,nonacm]{acmart}
\usepackage{oz}
\begin{document}
Hello, world!
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please show a minimal example? Is the “old package” a secret one?

Comment: It's this one: https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/objectz

Comment: @DavidCarlisle what you suggested doesn't compile at all and fails with `Missing number, treated as zero.` error

Comment: oz.sty ! oh wow, vague reminder of a previous life in a previous century:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default definition of `\baselinestretch` in the LaTeX kernel is empty and the `oz` package wants to modify the kernel macro `\@setfontsize` in such a way that also the internal `\zedbaselineskip` parameter is adjusted at each font size change. It does

```
\def\@setfontsize#1#2#3{\@nomath#1%
    \ifx\protect\@typeset@protect
      \let\@currsize#1%
    \fi
    \fontsize{#2}{#3}\selectfont
\setlength{\zedbaselineskip}{\baselineskip/\real{\baselinestretch}}%
    \zedbaselineskip\zedbaselinestretch\zedbaselineskip
    \setbox\zstrutbox\hbox{\vrule height.7\zedbaselineskip
    depth.3\zedbaselineskip width\z@}}
```

where the part from `\setlength` is added. It's pure luck that `\@setfontsize` hasn't been changed in the last 23 years… Anyway, the problem is the division by `\baselinestretch`, so the packages takes the initiative to do

```
\def\baselinestretch{1}
```

Well, it was a very unfortunate decision, in my opinion, just to avoid a simple conditional, see the proposed fix.

The `acmart` class sets `\baselinestretch` to `1.25` and refuses to compile if the value is changed. So you *must* reset the baseline stretch to the previous value after loading `oz`, or the appearance of the document will not conform the ACM standards.

Since you probably use the package `oz` also in other documents, you should also fix it so that it does *not* take inappropriate initiatives such as changing `\baselinestretch` without warning.

```
\documentclass{acmart}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for this example

\let\savedbaselinestretch\baselinestretch
\usepackage{oz}
\let\baselinestretch\savedbaselinestretch

% fix the bad part in oz.sty
\makeatletter
\def\@setfontsize#1#2#3{%
  \@nomath#1%
  \ifx\protect\@typeset@protect
    \let\@currsize#1%
  \fi
  % addition by oz.sty
  \fontsize{#2}{#3}\selectfont
  \ifx\baselinestretch\@empty
    \setlength{\zedbaselineskip}{\baselineskip}%
  \else
    \setlength{\zedbaselineskip}{\baselineskip/\real{\baselinestretch}}%
  \fi
  \zedbaselineskip\zedbaselinestretch\zedbaselineskip
  \sbox\zstrutbox{%
    \vrule height.7\zedbaselineskip depth.3\zedbaselineskip width\z@
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{schema}{BirthdayBook}
    known: \pset NAME \\
    birthday: NAME \pfun DATE
\ST
    known = \dom birthday
\end{schema}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The output with the “fix” proposed by David Carlisle would be

[image]

which would probably cause rejection of your submission anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can update the macro the ACM is testing, but don't do this for ACM submissions (and why use `acmart` if it is not an ACM submission?)

```
\documentclass[sigplan,nonacm]{acmart}
\usepackage{oz}

\makeatletter
\let\ACM@origbaselinestretch\baselinestretch
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Hello, world!

\end{document}
```

Comment: This will produce a document not conforming to the ACM standard that wants a 1.25 baseline stretch.

Comment: @egreg yes that's why I said not to do this in an ACM submission, but presumably  the OP wants other aspects of the class. The question asks to silence the warning, not to avoid changing baselinesretch